# Canvas With Rounded Corners Xaml Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Good day, I want to have my canvas have rounded corners. i know you place the canvas inside a Border Tag and round from there like

```
<Border>
  <Canvas>
  </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Now the solutions i have seen, they have an element in their Xaml called ClipToBounds Which makes the canvas adjust to the border but it is not present for SilverLight. so is there a way i can have this feature or an alternative so that the Canvas clips correctly to the Border? Thanks in Advance.

P.S i know i can set the canvas to transparent and the border background to the background i want the canvas to take, but am still learning windows phone so am trying to know as much solutions as possible in case that always doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: I used this, it works well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36495/Silverlight-ClipToBounds-Can-I-Clip-It-Yes-You-Can

Answer (score 0):

You can use Canvas.Clip:

```
<Canvas Height="100" Width="100" Background="white">
     <Canvas.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="50, 50" RadiusX="68" RadiusY="68" />                        
     </Canvas.Clip> 
   </Canvas>
```

Also, here's a handy tutorial if you wish to define your own ClipToBounds behaviour:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36495/Silverlight-ClipToBounds-Can-I-Clip-It-Yes-You-Can

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. but the Canvas.Clip doesn't seem to be doing anything or is the Center attribute wrong?

Comment: Did you make changes to the size of the Canvas? If so, you will have to adjust the Center, RadiusX and RadiusY values